# efficient way to show an <img> beside each instance <td>

Tags: css, html, image

I know how to use CSS and I'm learning Java, so if an answer happens to contain either language, i can compensate. But, i can always hope for a one-liner. :)

If it helps, all src atributes will be very similar for the images.

This is a small sample of a project i'm working on. I'm looking for a way to efficiently show an image beside above, or beside each card's name.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<table class="sentenceCase" id="mainTable"><tr class="notSentenceCase" id="title"><td colspan="10">Name censored Cube</td></tr>
    <tr class="notSentenceCase">
        <td class="description">bla bla bla irrelevant information</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rarityRow">
        <td class="empty" ></td>
        <td class="rarity-common" colspan="3">common</td>
        <td class="rarity-uncommon" colspan="3">uncommon</td>
        <td class="rarity-rare" colspan="3">rare</td>
    <tr> <!--White starts here-->
        <td class="colorName" rowspan="4">white</td>
        <td>porcelain legionnaire</td>  <td><img 
        src="http://www.wizards.com/global/images/magic/ZEN/cliff_threader.jpg"
        alt="Cliff Threader"
        border="0"
        height="200px"
        > 
        cliff threader </td>    <td class="lastInRow">marsh threader</td>
        <!--To expand, copy this row ^^ *Also do this in the next three blocks VV-->
        <td>suppression field</td>  <td>bathe in light</td> <td class="lastInRow">cloudgoat ranger</td>
        <td>gideon jura</td>    <td>eight-and-a-half tails</td> <td>tivadar of thorn</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>purelace</td>   <td>trade caravan</td>  <td class="lastInRow">auramancer</td>
        <td>auriok bladewarden</td> <td>ivory giant</td>    <td class="lastInRow">crip swap</td>
        <td>parallax wave</td>  <td></td>   <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>otherworldly journey</td>   <td>bonds of faith</td> <td class="lastInRow">avian changeling</td>
        <td></td>   <td></td>   <td class="lastInRow"></td>
        <td></td>   <td></td>   <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>   <td></td>   <td class="lastInRow"></td>
        <td></td>   <td></td>   <td class="lastInRow"></td>
        <td></td>   <td></td>   <td></td>
    </tr> <!--White ends here-->
```

Comment: background-image property in css doesn't work?

Comment: `I know how to use CSS and I'm learning Java`. Java != JavaScript!

Comment: You say "beside each card's name", but there's nothing mentioning cards in your code.  It's also confusing why you'd mention Java, which really has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I'm sorry for implying, but it becomes obvious once the file is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with `:before` and `:after` **pseudo-elements**?

```
td.card:after {
    content: url(image_url);
}
```

These pseudo-elements should come very handy in your case. You don't need to put an image beside every *card*. You simply add `card` class to whichever `td`s you want and style them with the proper CSS.

[Here's a nice article about it](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/)

Comment: Thank you kindly. I'm convinced this will work. If not, i will comment once again here. :)